# ViewPager destroys fragment when orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Im currently trying to understand why the viewpager destroys the fragment when the screen orientation change from portrait to landscape.

This is the **ViewPagerAdapter.kt**

```
internal class FragmentPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, private val mNumbOfTabs: Int) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    /**
     * return the fragment for each position
     */
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            SIGN_UP -> return SignUpFragment()
            LOGIN -> return LoginFragment()
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val ret = super.instantiateItem(container, position)
        return ret
    }

    /**
     * return number of tabs
     */
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mNumbOfTabs
    }

    companion object {
        private val SIGN_UP = 0
        private val LOGIN = 1
    }
}
```

and the way how i call it from the MainActivity

```
Handler().postDelayed({
                fadeOutAndHideImage(imagelogo);
                tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.sign_in).setText(R.string.sign_up))
                tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.sign_in).setText(R.string.login))
                val adapter = FragmentPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, tabs.getTabCount())
                viewpager.setAdapter(adapter)
                viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)
                viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
                tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
                    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                        // Hide keyboard
                        (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).hideSoftInputFromWindow(viewpager.getWindowToken(), 0)
                        viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.position)
                    }

                    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

                    }

                    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

                    }
                })
            }, 5000)
```

The screen goes well in landscape, however when i change to portrait well... i think that the images talk by themself. Some similar questions said something about retain the fragment.

This is the link of the app in bitbucket: https://Crdzbird@bitbucket.org/unidevelop/healthy-app.git

[Fragment + ViewPager fail when orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735561/fragment-viewpager-fail-when-orientation-change)

[Android ViewPager orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478968/android-viewpager-orientation-change)

[ViewPager fragments disappear when change screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075853/viewpager-fragments-disappear-when-change-screen-rotation)

but the result it's different :(

[image: Landscape]

[image: Portrait]

[[EDITED]]

The **SplashLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.freelance.nicaragua_dev.healthyapp.UI.SplashActivity">

    <com.freelance.nicaragua_dev.healthyapp.Helper.Kenburns.KenBurnsView
        android:id="@+id/ken_burns_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagelogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <com.freelance.nicaragua_dev.healthyapp.Helper.Kenburns.KenBurnsView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/material_petal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewPrincipal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="22dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the **SignUp.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".UI.SignUpFragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:gravity="center|left|bottom"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:gravity="center|left|bottom"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                android:text="@string/sign_up"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/red_button"
                android:textColor="@color/md_red_600" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use different layouts for different orientations?

Comment: No, the layout it's the same for both orientations

Comment: Post the xml layout for the viewpager as well

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your activity_splash.xml layout. The cardViewPrincipal has a bottom margin of 150dp and a top margin of 80dp. Reduce those values as most screens will not have enough real-estate for such high margin. The second reason is that you've set the viewpager to have a weight of 1 instead of just making match its parent.
Bonus (Not related to your  question entirely)
You should also replace the RelativeLayout with a FrameLayout as it is *expensive*. You should avoid using it as it will slow down your frame rate.

**Your xml should be like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.freelance.nicaragua_dev.healthyapp.UI.SplashActivity">

    <com.freelance.nicaragua_dev.healthyapp.Helper.Kenburns.KenBurnsView
        android:id="@+id/ken_burns_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagelogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <com.freelance.nicaragua_dev.healthyapp.Helper.Kenburns.KenBurnsView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/material_petal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/buttonSignup"-->
            <!--android:text="@string/sign_up"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="150dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="50dp"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/red_button"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@android:color/white" />-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewPrincipal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="22dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now everything goes perfect :) you sir are a live saver! :D

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same layout for portrait mode as well as landscape mode, you can edit your `AndroidManifest.xml`, and add this line to the `Activity` you don't want to redraw:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

> Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not
>   restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to
>   onConfigurationChanged().

Maybe that's what you are looking for in this case.

Alternatively you can clear the `Bundle` being passed to `onCreate()` since this object can contain some data which the `ViewPager` might use in a bad way.

Comment: The orientation i already have stablished as you suggest, however, the viewpager always keeps changing my fragment :(

Comment: What if you make `Bundle` null, like: `super.onCreate(null)`? In your `Activity`?